# How to handle FETCH_ERROR in RTK Query

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, fetch, http-status-code-401, rtk-query

I am requesting the server in localhost for some information using RTK Query. But when the server is not running it showing FETCH_ERROR. I want to handle this error. i.e when this happen i want to show a toast notification. But I can't catch this error. So I need help to do that

[Have look how the error looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iv1lY.png)

Answer (score 0):

This could be a way to do that

```js
const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
  baseUrl: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL,
  mode: "cors",
  prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
    // Set your headers
    return headers;
  },
});

const baseQueryWithLogout: BaseQueryFn<
  string | FetchArgs,
  unknown,
  FetchBaseQueryError
> = async (args, api, extraOptions) => {
  let result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions);
  if (result.error && result.error.status === "FETCH_ERROR") {
    // Handle your notification here
    return Promise.reject("Error");
  }
  return result;
};
```

If `result.error.status` is not exactly what you're looking for then you can play with the value that best suit your use case

Comment: That takes a "handled" error and makes it "unhandled", causing all kinds of problems within RTK Query. Never `return Promise.reject` within a `baseQuery`. `return { error: ... }` instead.